# how to get drug database for free?

Tags: data-request, drugs

where can I download from a database of drugs that will contain the information about drug indications/use, side effects, and drug interaction for free? Please tell me if you know. I want to use that for my online pharmacy store.

Or I want to know that is there any API to show such information about drug on my own website?

Comment: possible duplicate of [I need a list of medications, diagnosises, and medical terms for a police report auto publication project](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4458/i-need-a-list-of-medications-diagnosises-and-medical-terms-for-a-police-report)

Answer (score 8):

It's hard to say without some more specific information, but RxNorm is probably the best place to start:

(2nd section is download/API access)

http://www.nlm.nih.gov/research/umls/rxnorm/

Answer (score 4):

you haven't precised the country of which you want the drugs data. For **France** there is the [Open Medic Database](http://data.opendatasoft.com/explore/?q=m%C3%A9dicaments&sort=modified) where you'll find data about every drugs available on the market, including consumption by zone area and indications/side effects given by the french health authorities ([Haute Autorité Sanitaire](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haute_Autorit%C3%A9_de_sant%C3%A9)).

Not sure if it'll help but still interesting :)

Answer (score 4):

The information you seek is in the Structured Product Label (SPL) that each drug labeller provides to the FDA.  The SPL is free and available through an API provided by the National Library of Medicine's DailyMed web service.  For more information visit: http://usgovxml.com/DataService.aspx?ds=DMEDWS

Note: the web service has been updated to allow retrieval of SPLs by drugName, labeller, NDC, etc.  Visit: https://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/webservices-help/v2/spls_api.cfm